# Find if a list of notes is having different currencies using Java 8 Lambda expressions

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8

I have a list of notes with every note having a specific currency. I want to return currency if all the notes have the same currency. And if anyone one of the notes is having a different currency then, throw Exception. How can I implement this using Java 8 lambda expressions?

```
    public class Money {
        private List<NoteTO> notes;

        public List<NoteTO> getNotes() {
            return notes;
        }

        public void setNotes(List<NoteTO> notes) {
            this.notes = notes;
        }
    }

    public class NoteTO {
        private Long noteId;
        private String currency;

        public Long getNoteId() {
            return noteId;
        }

        public void setNoteId(Long noteId) {
            this.noteId = noteId;
        }

        public String getCurrency() {
            return currency;
        }

        public void setCurrency(String currency) {
            this.currency = currency;
        }
    }
```

I have achieved this through the following. But, want to do the same using Lambda expression.

```
    public void testMethod(){
        String currencyResponse = null;
        for(NoteTO note : notes){
            currencyResponse = checkCurrency(currencyResponse, note);
        }

        System.out.println("Currency : "+currencyResponse);
    }

    public String checkCurrency(String currencyResponse, NoteTO note) throws Exception {
        String currency = note.getCurrency();

        if(currencyResponse == null){
            return currency;
        } else if(!currencyResponse.equals(currency)){
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return currencyResponse;
    }
```

Comment: I have achieved without Java 8. But want to use lambda expression for the same.

Comment: Please post the non java8 code you have

Comment: Please [edit] the question

Comment: `notes.stream().map(Note::getCurrency).distinct().count()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Stream::allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-).

```
List<Note> notes = ...;

String currency = notes.isEmpty() ? null : notes.get(0).getCurrency();
if(!notes.stream().allMatch(e -> currency.equals(e.getCurrency())))
    throw new Exception();

System.out.println("Currency : " + currency);
```

Note that you can not throw exceptions from a lambda (in this case). So you have do a separate check for that.